# How to build a working jar file in Vaadin 14 + Spring Boot?

Tags: java, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

Im trying to run my Vaadin14 project to production and my application cant find any vaadin flow components. I have a default application.properties and POM, and downloaded it from here https://vaadin.com/start/latest. I already have tried,

delete node modules
mvn clean
mvn clean install -Pproduction
mvn clean package -Pproduction

and I get this error

```
Failed to find the following imports in the `node_modules` tree:
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/contextMenuConnector-es6.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/comboBoxConnector.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/gridConnector.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/contextMenuConnector.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/flow-component-renderer.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/gridConnector-es6.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/comboBoxConnector-es6.js
  - @vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-grid-flow-selection-column.js
```

If the build fails, check that npm packages are installed.

To fix the build remove `node_modules` directory to reset modules.
  In addition you may run `npm install` to fix `node_modules` tree structure.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

nvm guys, already found the answer.. Vaadin 14.0.11v

add this to your application.properties

vaadin.productionMode = true <----- comment this line when in dev mode

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = false